# continuous deployment and database

Tags: database, agile, continuous-deployment, netflix, continuous-delivery

In continuous deployment you sometimes gradually upgrade your servers, e.g 2 out of 20 will use the new code until we are convinced everything is ok. What would happen if the new code requires a database schema migration, e.g. field phone is now table Phones. Unless I'm upgrading all 20 servers something is going to break.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the expand/contract database pattern:
http://exortech.com/blog/2009/02/01/weekly-release-blog-11-zero-downtime-database-deployment/

You temporarily duplicate data such that things are in both the old and new locations. Old queries must work, and new ones as well. You can have automated tests in your test environments verify this. Once all servers move to the newer version, you execute the "contract" removing the "old" style data.

Comment: who duplicates the data? an old application server does not know nothing about the new tables

Comment: Your update scripts. So the data is both left in place where the old application servers are expecting it, and moved to its new location where the new application servers are expecting it. It's not a trivial approach, but can help in this scenario.

Comment: the update script runs once. after that "old" app servers will store new data in its old location. Not sure who will copy the data then.

Answer (score 0):

We do this all the time in our application. What we do is have the application check which "version" of the database it's working with and then make methods that work conditional. Basically the application will work correctly with both old and new scenarios.

Comment: but there is only one database for both "old" and "new" servers. so a new server can insert a new "phone" value in table Phones, while old servers (which know nothing on the change) will look for it in the regular phone field and not find it.